# Randomly choosing items from a list of items

Tags: r, random

I have the following

```
cells = c(3, 5, 8, 6)
names(cells) = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
```

I want to randomly choose half the cells, and assign then to a new vector m1, and the other half of the cells will be assigned to m2 = cells - m1. I'm new to R, and the sample function only allows me choose all the cells of one type, instead of an individual cell at a time, so I'm unsure of where to go from here.

My code currently looks like this

```
y = ceiling(sum(cells)/2)


for(i in 1:y){

   z = sample(cells[cells>0], 1, replacement = FALSE, prob = NULL)

   if(z == cells[1]){
      cells[1] = cells[1] - 1
      m1[1] = m1[1] + 1
   }
   if(z == cells[2]){
      cells[2] = cells[2] - 1
      m1[2] = m1[2] + 1
   }
   if(z == cells[3]){
      cells[3] = cells[3] - 1
      m1[3] = m1[3] + 1
   } 
   if(z == cells[4]){
      cells[4] = cells[4] - 1
      m1[4] = m1[4] + 1
   }
}
```

I know this is wrong as it only chooses the cell type randomly, instead of choosing each cell randomly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `sample(..., replace = FALSE)`. Can you change that so your code is reproducible and also provide an example of the desired output?

Comment: @rmk - It is best not fix code errors in *questions*, because it may obscure the actual problem that brought someone here. If you see a potential problem with the code, leave a comment or post an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of sampling from `cells` directly, sample indexes and use those to choose your elements.

```
cells = c(3, 5, 8, 6)
categories = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')

n  = length(cells)
cells_long = unlist(sapply(1:n
                          , function(i){ rep(categories[i],cells[i]) }
                          ))

n  = length(cells_long)
ix = sample(1:n, floor(n/2))
m1 = cells_long[ix]
m2 = cells_long[-ix]
```

This is a useful trick for sampling from complex objects or collections of related objects as well.

Comment: Hey, looks like your new. Welcome to SO! If this solved your problem, you should click the checkmark below the answer score to "accept" the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why not define `cells = c(rep('A',3),rep('B',5), rep('C',8), rep('D',6))` and then

```
    > cells
     [1] "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "D" "D" "D"
    [20] "D" "D" "D"

    x <- sample(1:length(cells), ceiling(length(cells)/2))

    m1 <- cells[x]
     [1] "D" "B" "C" "A" "B" "A" "B" "D" "D" "C" "C"

    m2 <- cells[setdiff(1:length(cells), x)]
     [1] "A" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "D" "D" "D"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use parameter prob in sample function

```
x <- sample(letters[1:4], 22, replace = T, prob = c(3,5,8,6))
x
[1] "d" "c" "a" "c" "b" "a" "b" "b" "b" "c" "b" "c" "d" "c" "c" "b" "c" "b" "c" "d" "c" "b"
m1 <- x[1:11]; m2 <- x[12:22]
```

Comment: That's a neat trick, but it's doesn't ensure the same distribution in the categories as he's starting with. Consider your example: your result for `x` only has two instances of 'a' when there ought to be 3.